# Hover function jquery issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a hover function, that once hovered will show more information of that div. However you can see that this isn't working as should be, with multiple firingand not hiding correctly.

I owuld like this so if hovered one of the divs, once hovered away this will then close (then if they are hovered on the second div, this will display that one).

A lot of the functionality is there already, I am just struggling with the final details of this.

Please see my codepen link below, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Codepen is here:- https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/VwwKJvW

```
<div class="row fourrow">
    <div class="colinfo extrainfo">
        <div id="col-hover-1" style="display: none;">
            <h3>Vision</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id luptatum appellantur vel, te nec consul delicatissimi. Nibh doctus nusquam at quo, qui ei malis graeco. Ubique nostrum et sed, eum ex graeco volumus epicuri. Te postea vituperata.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="col-hover-2" style="display: none;">
            <h3>Insight</h3>        
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id luptatum appellantur vel, te nec consul delicatissimi. Nibh doctus nusquam at quo, qui ei malis graeco. Ubique nostrum et sed, eum ex graeco volumus epicuri. Te postea vituperata.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="col-hover-3" style="display: none;">
            <h3>Technology</h3>     
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id luptatum appellantur vel, te nec consul delicatissimi. Nibh doctus nusquam at quo, qui ei malis graeco. Ubique nostrum et sed, eum ex graeco volumus epicuri. Te postea vituperata.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="col-hover-4" style="display: none;">
            <h3>Confidence</h3>     
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id luptatum appellantur vel, te nec consul delicatissimi. Nibh doctus nusquam at quo, qui ei malis graeco. Ubique nostrum et sed, eum ex graeco volumus epicuri. Te postea vituperata.</p>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col col1" data-contentid="1">
        <p>The <strong>vision</strong> to understand your culture and goals. </p>
        <h2>Vision</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col col2" data-contentid="2">
        <p>The intelligence to source just the right candidates.</p>
        <h2>Insight</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col col3" data-contentid="3">
        <p>The <strong>technology</strong> to complete rigorous assessments, fast. </p>
        <h2>Technology</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col col4" data-contentid="4">
        <p>The <strong>mindset</strong> to represent your business on your behalf. </p>
        <h2>Confidence</h2>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fourrow {position: relative;display:flex;width:1500px;margin:auto;}


.colinfo {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 0;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;

}
.extrainfo {
    background: #c2281b;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #fff;

}

.extrainfo, .extrainfo > div {pointer-events:none;}

.extrainfo h3, .extrainfo p {
    color:#fff;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
}

.fourrow .col {
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: right;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    position: relative;
    color:#fff;
}

.fourrow h2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.fourrow .col:nth-child(2) {background-image:url(http://www.project-progress.co.uk/ashfield/superhero/wp-content/uploads/vision.png);}
.fourrow .col:nth-child(3) {background-image:url(http://www.project-progress.co.uk/ashfield/superhero/wp-content/uploads/insight.png);}
.fourrow .col:nth-child(4) {background-image:url(http://www.project-progress.co.uk/ashfield/superhero/wp-content/uploads/technology.png);}
.fourrow .col:nth-child(5) {background-image:url(http://www.project-progress.co.uk/ashfield/superhero/wp-content/uploads/confidence.png);}


.fourrow .col p {
    width:60%;
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){


jQuery(".col").mouseover(function(){
  $(".extrainfo").css("opacity", "1");
    $(".extrainfo p, .extrainfo h3").css("opacity", "0");
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $(".extrainfo p, .extrainfo h3").css("opacity", "1"), 1500;
    }, 1000);       
  $(".extrainfo").stop().animate({width: '100%'}, 1000);
  var num = $(this).data('contentid');
  jQuery('#col-hover-' + num).toggle();
    $(".col").css("pointer-events", "none");
    $(this).css("pointer-events", "auto");
});

jQuery(".col").mouseout(function(){
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $(".col").css("pointer-events", "auto");
    }, 1500);   
  $(".extrainfo").stop().animate({width: '0'}, 1000);
  var num = $(this).data('contentid');
  jQuery('#col-hover-' + num).toggle();
});


});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what isn't working. When I look at your CodePen, everything seems to be functioning properly. Could you elaborate with a bit more detail?

Comment: However, on a side note, I'm not entirely sure what the ", 1500" a the end of this line is for... 

$(".extrainfo p, .extrainfo h3").css("opacity", "1"), 1500;

Comment: Other than tweaks that could be made to the CSS, it seems like everything is working. They only comment I would make is that it might be a little easier to manage the code if you use the jQuery hover function instead of the mouseover and mouseout functions. That's just personal preference though.